# What software do I need to read-write cas9? and .dna files?

Tags: crispr, software

I am still a complete beginner to crispr and I am still trying to learn what it is and how to actually use it. I now realise that you have to order the crispr components after you have actually designed them yourself in software that lets you design and alter the components.

Am I correct so far?

I am wondering if anyone could help me find which software I should use to design and or alter .dna files . Preferably free and open-source software. Are there any good tutorials for someone who wants to get more into crispr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a long journey ahead. This guy spent about 4 years to learn what he is doing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Rv6aMdKY40).

He is using Snapgene software

Comment: Thank you! :) The site doesn´t allow me to upvote because I have a to low reputation but know that I am really thankful! :)

Comment: I use Snapgene for my work the interface is nice, but with the free version you can't edit files to insert/delete bases.